# Where IN() raising an error in Postgres when array is empty

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

This line would previously work in SQlite. But now I've switched to postgreSQL it's raising an exception if the array is empty.

```
InstagramMedia.where(instagram_account: [self.instagram_accounts.ids])
```

What's the most efficient way to rephrase this so that PostgreSQL will be happy? when `self.instagram_accounts.ids` is empty

Thanks

EDIT
The error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...media"  WHERE "instagram_media"."instagram_account_id" IN ()
                                                                      ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "instagram_media"  WHERE "instagram_media"."instagram_account_id" IN ():
```

And it only occours when the array is empty

Comment: What is `self.instagram_accounts`? Is there a relation behind that?

Comment: Hey, yes, a user has many instagram_accounts which in turn has many instagram_media. I thought of using delegate but that didn't seem to fit for me.. so I decided to create a method that retrieves a users media like this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails and Postgres are you on?

Passing an empty array to in `#where` should not raise an error:

```
(Rails 4.2.6 and Postgres 9.4)
>> User.where(id: [])
>> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE  1=0
[]
```

It looks like your `self.instagram_accounts.ids` is probably returning an array, meaning that you are passing a nested array. This capability was deprecated in 4.2 but I believe was removed in 5.0. Could this be the source of your error?

> WARN  DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a nested array to Active Record
>   finder methods is deprecated and will be removed. Flatten your array
>   before using it for 'IN' conditions.

Can you post the whole error if this is not the case?

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that's the issue. I've added the error message to my question